# Finding period of $\sin^2(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Define $f(x)=\sin^2(x)$. I understand that we can use the identity $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ to find the period of $f(x)$, but I wanted to do it differently and my approach seems to fail, but I don't see any flaw in the reasoning... My "solution" was this ($T$ - period):
$$f(x+T)=f(x) \rightarrow \sin^2(x+T)-\sin^2(x)=0 \rightarrow$$ $$ \sin(x+T)=\sin(x) \vee \sin(x+T)=-\sin(x)$$
From the first alternative: $T = 2k\pi$, and from the second $T=-2x+2n\pi$ ($k,n \in Z$). What's wrong here?

Comment: Finding the period of $\sin^2(x)$ is very easy, do you mean the fundamental period?

Comment: I know it is, but my method yields wrong result... I was asking to help me find a mistake in it

Comment: Do you know the difference between a period and a fundamental period? A period is any non-zero $T$ such that $f(x+T) = f(x)$. A fundamental period is the smallest positive period.

Comment: Or perhaps you mean finding all the periods of $\sin^2(x)$ ?

Comment: Just tell me where I made a mistake in the above calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that in general

$$\sin^2 A= \sin^2 B \iff \sin A = \pm \sin B$$

and

$$\sin A =  \sin B \iff A=B \quad \lor \quad A=\pi-B+2k\pi$$

$$\sin A =  -\sin B \iff A=-B \quad \lor \quad A=\pi+B+2k\pi$$

that is with $A=x$ and $B=x+T$ we obtain

- $x=x+T+2k\pi\implies T=2k\pi$
- $x=\pi-(x+T)+2k\pi\implies T=\pi-2x+2k\pi$
- $x=-(x+T)+2k\pi\implies T=-2x+2k\pi$
- $x=\pi+(x+T)+2k\pi\implies T=\pi+2k\pi$

$$\implies T_{min}=\pi$$

Comment: Cool! Now I see! I forgot that $\sin(x)=\sin(a)\ \rightarrow x=a+2k\pi AND x=\pi-a+2k\pi$!!

Comment: @A.J.Bałaziński You are welcome! Bye